# Search speed in Elastic does not depend on the use of the analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use elastic search in my project. Created an index

```json
curl --location --request PUT 'http://localhost:9200/customers' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 40,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "index": {
        "max_ngram_diff" : "37"
    }
  }
}'
```

Added 200 thousand records, I search for all fields in the query

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:9200/customers/_search?q=*2000018*' --header 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

And the bottom line is that if I create an index without a parser, then the speed remains the same,
I used ngram in the first case, and, in principle, was pleased with the speed of work, but decided to make sure that this is really due to the fact that it is configured correctly, but without it the situation is similar, it turns out that it does not affect in any way and that means I have something- what i do wrong

I tried to find the answer in the documentation and similar questions, but still can't figure out what I am doing wrong

I will be glad for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It looks like that you have defined the `analyzer` ONLY in the `settings` part.**

You need to define the analyzer in the `mappings` part also.

You need to add the `analyzer` setting that will point to the `my_analyzer` analyzer that will be used at the index time.

Refer to this official ES documentation, to know more about [`analyzer`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer.html)

---

Suppose the field on which you want to use the `ngram` is `title`. Below will be the modified index mapping for that case -

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 40,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "index": {
      "max_ngram_diff": "37"
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```